# Git for Windows Python print not working when DEBUG/LOG too?

Tags: python, windows, printing, output

When I run my Python script, my print statements do not get written to the output/screen (see output below). However, in a normal Windows console/prompt (and macOs) it works: both log and print messages are written to stdout (mixed).

```
DEBUG:session_storage:session:getter: MainThread
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Resetting dropped connection: example.com
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://example.com:443 "GET /QW/7720d5b252de HTTP/1.1" 200 1073
before api init
!!setting session
b
after api init
after request init
Process  X-1  is running.
Got a valid value from queue
```

When I it CRTL-C the the text from 'before api init' onwards get printed (so after program execution).

Code:

```
# SETUP LOGGING
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

def main():

  #another process is created via multiprocessing (process duplicated?)
  ...

  logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Maybe it has to do with the multiprocessing part?

Comment: Not related to git, so removing the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more than likely that **buffering of output** is to blame. Try flushing and messages should show up

```
# for stdout
sys.stdout.flush()

# for stderr
sys.stderr.flush()
```

Comment: I will try that (as soon I got access to my other computer)

Comment: This works. Thank you.